# linux + port in use + but no PID return from netstat to kill the PID

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, netstat, port

we have Hadoop cluster - the linux are rhel 7.5 machines

and namenode is using the port 50070

we can see from the log that port 50070 is in use

but the interesting thing is that when we do `netstat -tulpn | grep 50070` , to find the PID , the its return nothing

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 50070   ( we not get output )
```

so how it can be ?

how to clear the port?

```
2020-07-18 21:26:22,753 INFO  impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:shutdown(606)) - NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2020-07-18 21:26:22,753 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1783)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.net.BindException: Port in use: linux.gg.com:50070
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.constructBindException(HttpServer2.java:1001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1023)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.openListeners(HttpServer2.java:1080)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.start(HttpServer2.java:937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeHttpServer.start(NameNodeHttpServer.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startHttpServer(NameNode.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:755)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:985)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1778)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindListener(HttpServer2.java:988)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2.bindForSinglePort(HttpServer2.java:1019)
        ... 9 more
2020-07-18 21:26:22,755 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2020-07-18 21:26:22,757 INFO  namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at 
************************************************************/
[root@linux hdfs]#
[root@linux hdfs]#
[root@linux hdfs]# netstat -tulpn | grep 50070 ( no PID number is returned )
```

Comment: Are you sure it's still open? There is a time where you can't immediately bind to a port that was in use. This tends to happen IIRC when the service doesn't close the port properly (say in the event of a crash).  If you use `netcat` you can test that your port finding `grep` call works. You can also use `nc` to connect to the port that you think is in use and see if anything answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages indicate the problem is with a HTTP server that belongs to Hadoop. Port 50070 is the default for HDFS web UI in Hadoop 2.7.1 and above, I think.

With `netstat -tulpn`, you are looking at ports listening for incoming TCP connections. And since the problem is with Hadoop's HTTP server, you don't need to look at UDP ports at all, since HTTP will only use a TCP port.

But since the port number is so high, it could be occupied by an *outgoing* connection instead. Try `netstat -tapn | grep 50070` instead.

To see the range of ports that can be dynamically allocated for outgoing connections, run `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. You can use `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = min_value max_value` in `/etc/sysctl.conf[.d]` to adjust the range, but restricting the range on a busy server that has a lot of outgoing connections might not be a good idea. The default range on my Debian 10 is from port 32768 to 60999; enterprise distributions may use an expanded range by default.

Instead, you might want to choose a non-default port for this HDFS web UI, that is outside the range of ports used for outgoing connections. The property `dfs.namenode.http-address` in `hdfs.xml` has a default value of `0.0.0.0:50070` if it is not set. You could set that property with a value of `0.0.0.0:<some_other_port>`.

In other words, to set the port number to e.g. 32070 instead, you could add this to your `hdfs.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:32070</value>
</property>
```

The `0.0.0.0` means "any IP address the system running the web UI has." You could replace it with an IP address, if the system has multiple network connections with different addresses and you want the HDFS web UI to be reachable in a single IP address only.

Of course, you'll also need to document that the HDFS web UI is now in a non-default port, so that the administrators who need the web UI functionality will be able to find it.